# How to update many to many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, many-to-many

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whdb6.png)

I have a many-to-many relationship between `students` and `courses` as shown.
I want to update the courses for a given student (ex `student Id = 10` has selected two courses with Id 2 and 6). I want to delete course Id 6 for student id 10 and add new course, say Id = 3.

I am using a code-first approach with Entity Framework 6 in ASP.NET MVC 4.

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uld8.png)

Comment: **DO NOT** post screenshots of your source code - post the code **itself** here and properly format it to be nicely syntax highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Your specifications weren't really clear about what you meant with the term "delete a Course": do you want to remove the Course from the database, so the Course does not exist anymore? Or do you want your Student to stop following this Course?

I'll describe both, therefore I have a student with 3 Courses:

- Id = 2: will not be changed; Student already followed this Course and will keep following this Course
- Id = 6: student will stop following this Course; Other Students might still be following this Course
- Id = 7: Course will be removed from the database

Furthermore you have:

- Id = 3: Student will start following this Course

---

### many-to-many in entity framework

If you've configured your many-to-many relation according to the [Entity Framework Code First many-to-many conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) You will have something similar as the following:

```
class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Student attends zero or more Courses (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses {get; set;}

    ... // other properties 
}

class Course
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Course is attended by zero or more Students
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}

public SchoolContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Course> Courses {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to know that you wanted to configure a many-to-many relationship between Students and Courses. Entity Framework will create the junction table with the foreign keys to the Students and Courses for you. Whenever you access the ICollections entity framework will know that a join with the junction table is needed.

This can be done without the use of Attributes or Fluent Api. These are only needed if you want to deviate from the conventions, for instance if you want different table names or column names.

### Back to your problem

We have the following Ids:

```
int idStudent = 10;
int idCourseToStartFollowing = 3;
int idCourseToStopFollowing = 6;
int idCourseToRemoveFromDb = 7;

using (var dbContext = new SchoolContext())
{
    // Fetch the Student to update (has id 10)
    Student studentToUpdate = dbContext.Students.Find(idStudent);

    // this student starts following Course with Id 3
    Course courseToStartFollowing = dbContext.Courses.Find(idCourseToStartFollowing);
    studentToUpdate.Courses.Add(courseToStartFollowing);

    // this student stops following Course with Id 6
    Course courseToStopFollowing = dbContext.Courses.Find(idCourseToStopFollowing);
    StudentToUpdate.Courses.Remove(courseToStopFollowing);

    // Remove Course with Id 7 from the database
    Course courseToRemove = dbContext.Find(idCourseToRemove);
    dbContext.Remove(courseToRemove);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Simple comme bonjour!